# Timeout and kill parallel matlab execution

Tags: linux, matlab, parfor

I have a matlab processing script located in the middle of a long processing pipeline running on linux.

The matlab script applies the same operation to a number `N` of datasets `D_i (i=1,2,...,N)` in parallel on (8 cores) via `parfor`. 
Usually, processing the whole dataset takes about 2hours (on 8 cores).

Unfortunately, from time to time, looks like one of the matlab subprocesses crashes randomly. This makes the job impossible to complete (and the pipeline can't finish).

I am sure this does not depend on the data as if I reprocess specifically the `D_i` on which the process crashes, it is executed without problems. Moreover, up to now I've processed already thousands of the mentioned dataset.

---

How I deal with the problem now (...manually...):

After I start the matlab job, I periodically check the process list on the machine (via a simple `top`); whenever I have one matlab process alive after two hours of work, then I know for sure that it has crashed. Then I simply kill it and process the part of the dataset which has not been analyzed.

---

Question:

I am looking for suggestion on how to timeout ALL the matlab processes running and kill them whenever they are alive for more than e.g. 2hrs CPU.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: @rwong, thanks. the processes should be killed depending on the CPU time though..Can I do it?

Comment: cron job, write a script to parse the cpu time from top. you can do a lot of things with scripts.

Comment: However, it would have been much better (i.e. more professional) to modify the MATLAB script to write out occasional log messages - for both progress percentage and unusual conditions (which might be numerical in the case of MATLAB), and also JVM memory stats. This way, the log files can help you discover why problems occur.

Comment: I see, what I can't get is the fact that it looks random. If I process the whole dataset say 5 times, I expect one process to crash once. I know exactly at which data element `D_i` it stopped, although if I reprocess `D_i` everything works fine.

Comment: I would attest for a bash based cron job too.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by restructuring your code to use [PARFEVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html) instead of PARFOR. There's a simple example in this entry on Loren's blog: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/12/09/getting-data-from-a-web-api-in-parallel/ which shows how you can stop waiting for work after a given amount of time.